# CRAS audio & video stopped working [Chromebook]

Tags: 13.10, sound, video, chromebook, chromeos

It all seemed to start after updating ChromeOS. (I'm running Ubuntu inside of ChromeOS (crouton))

I have no audio, (and video is hit-and-miss, either broken or working).
I tried to manually turn the volume up with command-line on the chance the keys may have gotten rebinded or something and get the error:

```
CRAS client wouldn't connect.
```

Then I tried to connect to HDMI (just to see if it would work) and got the error:

```
Gstreamer was unable to detect sound devices (paraphrasing)
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.. a lot of errors I can deal with, but no audio/video is super inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome OS updates sometimes break CRAS audio in Ubuntu, and just a few days ago there was such an update which broke mine.

See https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/839

I had the exact same issue and output as the OP there, but updating the chroot worked for me! Might have something to do with me running trusty (vs OP running saucy).